ArcGIS Map Layers Turned Black After Editing in Map Viewer Classic – How to Fix or Roll Back?"
I created a map using the ArcGIS Map Viewer and later made edits to one of the layers using Map Viewer Classic. However, after saving the changes, I noticed that all the layers in my map turned black when viewed. I searched for a way to roll back these changes but couldn’t find an option to revert to a previous state.
enter image description here
Here are the main points of my issue:

The map was initially created in the standard Map Viewer.
Changes were made to a layer using Map Viewer Classic.
After these edits, all layers appear black in the map.
I need guidance on whether there's a way to resolve this issue or roll back to a previous version.

Has anyone faced a similar problem, or is there a solution to recover my map's original state? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I tried to revert my changes by deleting the new layer I added and opening the map in the Map Viewer.

Are you using Map Viewer and Map Viewer Classic in ArcGIS Online or in Portal for ArcGIS?
Have you looked at your web map in the ArcGIS Online Assistant? https://ago-assistant.esri.com/
